# Why is this bash loop failing to concatenate the files?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, concatenation

I am at my wits end as to why this loop is failing to concatenate the files the way I need it. Basically, lets say we have following files:

```
AB124661.lane3.R1.fastq.gz
AB124661.lane4.R1.fastq.gz

AB124661.lane3.R2.fastq.gz
AB124661.lane4.R2.fastq.gz
```

What we want is:

```
cat AB124661.lane3.R1.fastq.gz AB124661.lane4.R1.fastq.gz > AB124661.R1.fastq.gz
cat AB124661.lane3.R2.fastq.gz AB124661.lane4.R2.fastq.gz > AB124661.R2.fastq.gz
```

What I tried (and didn't work):

1. Create and save file names (AB124661) to a ID file:

> ls -1 *R1*.gz | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq > ID

This creates an ID file that stores the samples/files name.

2. Run the following loop:

> ```
> for i in `cat ./ID`; do cat $i\.lane3.R1.fastq.gz $i\.lane4.R1.fastq.gz \> out/$i\.R1.fastq.gz; done
>     
> for i in `cat ./ID`; do cat $i\.lane3.R2.fastq.gz $i\.lane4.R2.fastq.gz \> out/$i\.R2.fastq.gz; done
> ```

The loop fails and concatenates into empty files.

Things I tried:

- Yes, the ID file is definitely in the folder
- When I run with echo it shows the cat command correct

Any help will be very much appreciated,

Best,

AC

Comment: [There's never a reason to use `ls` in a script.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `ls -1 R1.gz` is just a slower version of `printf '%s\n' "R1.gz"`

Comment: If you concatinate two gzip compressed files, you get no valid file.

Comment: @Cyrus, eh? gzip streams can be concatenated; `gunzip` will just decompress them in sequence.

Comment: Try running `{ gzip -c <<<"hello"; gzip -c <<<"world"; } | gunzip`

Comment: @Cyrus The man page of `gzip` clearly states that _"Multiple  compressed  files  can  be concatenated. In this case, gunzip will extract all members at once."_

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I have expressed myself unclearly. I assume that each archive contains a different file. After unpacking, you do not get two files but one concatenated file.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that's correct. Doesn't the OP _want_ a single concatenated file?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, if that is the case, then I have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. why are you escaping the `\>` ? That's going to result in a `cat: '>': No such file or directory` instead of a redirection.
2. [Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

```bash
while IFS= read -r id; do
    cat "${id}.lane3.R1.fastq.gz" "${id}.lane4.R1.fastq.gz" > "out/${id}.R1.fastq.gz"
    cat "${id}.lane3.R2.fastq.gz" "${id}.lane4.R2.fastq.gz" > "out/${id}.R2.fastq.gz"
done < ./ID
```

Comment: No reason to uncompress before concatenating with gzip; the streams can be directly concatenated while compressed and the decompressor won't care.

Comment: (this is a deliberate design feature: it lets you get things like "rsyncable gzip", where the compressed stream is periodically reset)

Comment: ...as I posted in a comment on the question: Try running `{ gzip -c <<<"hello"; gzip -c <<<"world"; } | gunzip`; you'll see both `hello` and `world` make it into the output.

Comment: I was looking in the man page but didn't read closely enough. Now that I see it it's quite plain: "Multiple compressed files can be concatenated."

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have id stored in file ./ID per line

```bash
while read -r line; do
    cat "$line".lane3.R1.fastq.gz "$line".lane4.R1.fastq.gz > "$line".R1.fastq.gz
    cat "$line".lane3.R2.fastq.gz "$line".lane4.R2.fastq.gz > "$line".R2.fastq.gz
done < ./ID
```

Comment: There's no benefit of `${line}` over `$line` in this use case, but using `"$line"` would be more correct, since it would mean that lines containing whitespace or characters in IFS would work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A pure shell solution could be like that:

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do
    id=${file%%.*}
    [ -e "$id".R1.fastq.gz ] || cat "$id".*.R1.fastq.gz > "$id".R1.fastq.gz
    [ -e "$id".R2.fastq.gz ] || cat "$id".*.R2.fastq.gz > "$id".R2.fastq.gz
done
```

Alternatively:

```
printf '%s\n' *.fastq.gz | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u |
while IFS= read -r id; do
    cat "$id".*.R1.fastq.gz > "$id".R1.fastq.gz
    cat "$id".*.R2.fastq.gz > "$id".R2.fastq.gz
done
```

This solution assumes filenames of interest don't contain newline characters.